# Differentiability of a function extended via symmetry

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Define a function $g$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$ by $g(x)=f(|x|)$. Then do I get that $g$ is differentiable on $(-\infty,\infty)$, or could $g$ not be differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Take $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of distributions, the derivative is $$  (f|x|)' = f'(|x|) )*   |x|' = f'(|x|) * \text{sign}(x) $$ which is continuous at $x=0$ only if $f'(0)=0$. $ x\in [0,\infty), f: x \to x$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

I think $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ gives a counterexample. This function is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ but $g(x)=|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is not differentiable at $0$.